# Estimating the mean of a random variable from greater than/less than answers

Tags: estimation, algorithms

Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be $n$ i.i.d. samples from a certain probability distribution (e.g, a normal distribution).

Your goal is to estimate the mean of the distribution.

However, you are not allowed to see the samples themselves.

You are allowed, in each time-step $t$, to select a number $Y_t$.

Then, you are told whether $X_t>Y_t$ or $X_t<Y_t$ or $X_t=Y_t$.

> How would you select the numbers $Y_t$?
>
> And how would you use the answers to estimate the mean?

(As a practical application, consider a person who sells a certain item and wants to estimate the average value of this item in the eyes of potential buyers. The real values are the $X_t$, but the seller cannot see them directly. In each time-step, the seller sets the price of the product to $Y_t$. Then, a buyer comes. If $X_t>Y_t$ then the buyer buys the item, otherwise the buyer just says "it's too expensive for me" and walks away. So the seller wants to estimate the average value based on this yes/no information).

Comment: Do we *know* that the $X_i$ are normally distributed? Do we know whether they are iid? Do we have *any* prior information? (E.g., in your price example, we know that real values are nonnegative, and smaller than the US GDP, so that tells us *something*.)

Comment: In your initial description you say you can distinguish the three cases (the two inequalities and the equality), but in your practical application, how would you distinguish the case of equality from both inequalities?

Comment: The practical application is *hugely* different from the statement of the question, because there is a clear *loss* involved with each setting of the price.  That version of the question cannot be resolved until you can tell us how to measure the losses when buyers do not buy the item.  (Clearly those losses exist: they are associated with the costs of the auction, of the wasted time, and potentially with being unable to sell the item.)

Comment: This is an excellent question. I'll give it a try later.

Comment: Do you have a prior on the mean and variance of $X_t$? Are both the mean and variance unknown?

Comment: Did you review some of the literature on bandits? Your question seems similar to the bandit problem

Comment: @StephanKolassa Yes, we know that they are normally distributed and i.i.d, but do not have any prior information.

Comment: @Glen_b since we deal with continuous distributions, the case in which $X_i=Y_i$ has zero probability, so I think it does not matter what you do in this case.

Comment: @whuber of course, the practical application is much more complicated than the actual question. The question isolates the estimation aspect of the application and ignores the loss aspect. Handling the loss is a good topic for a new question...

Comment: Actually, I'm thinking that your problem could also be recast as that of finding a bayes-optimal classifier. The classifier is entirely defined by $\mu$, and the decision rule is $\mathbf{1}_{ \{y - \mu > 0\} }$. There is probably plenty of literature on active learning for linear classification problems, see e.g. [this review](http://burrsettles.com/pub/settles.activelearning.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my take on this question. I will assume that:

1. $X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$, and the $X_i$'s are independent
2. $\mu$ is unknown
3. $\sigma^2$ is known (I'll discuss this assumption later.)

#### Part 1: ML estimation given some data

First, consider the case where we are given some data, and we want to estimate $\mu$. Denote the data by $\mathcal{D} = \{ (y_i, t_i) \mid i = 1, \ldots, n \}$, where $y_i \in \mathbf{R}$ and
$$
t_i = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $X_i$ > $y_i$} \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Note that I use a lowercase letter for $y_i$ to emphasize that it is a value that we can observe, as opposed to $X_i$.

We have
$$
P(t_i = 1 \mid y_i) = P(X_i > y_i) = \Phi\left( \frac{\mu - y_i}{\sigma} \right)
$$
and the likelihood of $\mu$ given the data is
$$
\ell(\mu ; \mathcal{D}) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} \left( \Phi\left( \frac{\mu - y_i}{\sigma} \right) \right)^{t_i} \left( 1- \Phi\left( \frac{\mu - y_i}{\sigma} \right) \right)^{1-t_i} \qquad (*)
$$
This function is log-concave, and has a unique maximizer if there is at least one $i$ such that $t_i = 1$, and at least one $i$ such that $t_i = 0$.
Furthermore, I suspect that the maximizer is independent of the value of $\sigma^2$ (to be checked).

#### Part 2: Active learning

I think this is the more interesting part. Here, we'll assume that you start with $\mathcal{D} = \varnothing$, and you want to iteratively pick a value $y_i$ and observe the corresponding $t_i$, in such a way that you "learn the most" about $\mu$.

There are many ways to go about this; in the following I'm taking a bayesian approach. We start by assuming a prior distribution on $\mu$, say
$$
\mu \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \tau^2)
$$
Given some data $\mathcal{D}$, your knowledge about $\mu$ is contained in the posterior distribution
$$
p(\mu \mid \mathcal{D}) \propto p(\mathcal{D} \mid \mu) p(\mu) 
$$
Unfortunately, this posterior is not analytically tractable for the likelihood given above $(*)$. One practical way to bypass this problem is to approximate the posterior with a Gaussian distribution that is "closest" to the true posterior, in some sense. In particular, [Expectation propagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation_propagation) and the [Variational Gaussian](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/c.archambeau/publ/neco_mo09_web.pdf) approximation come to mind.

One way to go about picking a value that leads to a lot of "information" about $\mu$ is to [greedily maximize the expected reduction in the entropy of the posterior](http://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/~chuwei/paper/gprl.pdf). Informally, the entropy of the posterior tells you how "unsure" you are about the value of $\mu$, and you'll want to pick a $y_i$ that is likely to reduce this uncertainty (I say "likely" because it will depend on the outcome $t_i$).

In this particular case, as we are just estimating a single parameter, reducing the entropy can be understood to be simply reducing the variance of the posterior.

**Conjecture**. let $p_i$ be the posterior on $\mu$ after $i$ steps (in particular, $p_0 = \mathcal{N}(0, \tau^2)$).
Then, the point $y_{i+1}$ that maximizes the expected reduction in posterior entropy is given by
$$
y_{i+1} = \mathbf{E}_{p_i}(\mu)
$$
Basically, my conjecture is saying: just sample at your current best guess for $\mu$!

Again, I believe that the assumption that $\sigma^2$ is fixed is not too important. I have the impression that what matters really is the ratio $\tau^2 / \sigma^2$. (This is again to be checked.)

Comment: I didn't read the whole answer because it appears to neglect the most important features of the question.  I had commented previously about how it's crucial to account for a loss function in the practical problem.  Another subtlety is that the question intends for the $y_i$ to depend on the previous results.  As such, the $y_i$ *are* random variables and they are dependent on the $X_i$.  Thus your likelihood is incorrect.

Comment: I focused on the (statistical) question of estimating the mean of the $X_i$'s. That's how I understood the OP's question. If one wants to penalize the number of "failures to sell", the problem becomes different indeed. As for the likelihood, I don't see why it's incorrect? The $y_i$'s could be chosen as a function of the $X_i$'s, but once chosen they are fixed.

Comment: When the $y_i$ are functions of the $X_i$, they are *random*.  Exactly how they are chosen has to determine the likelihood.  The issue of stipulating the loss goes to the heart of the statistical matter: if it's not accounted for, then any further analysis is either meaningless or misleading.

Comment: @lum This is an interesting answer with interesting references. If I understand correctly, and if your conjecture is correct, the learning algorithm is as follows: (1) start by arbitrarily guessing some values of $y_i$, until you get at least one "greater than" and one "less than" answer. (2) Based on the answers, calculate the maximum-likelihood estimate of the mean. (3) From now on, in time $t$, guess a value $y_t$ that is equal to the current estimate, and update the estimate according to the outcome. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @whuber the question deliberately ignores the loss aspect of the application in order to better understand the estimation aspect. Your comment about the $y_i$ being random variables is interesting and I am trying to think whether this issue can be fixed.

Comment: @Erel By ignoring the loss, you completely change the question.  That is such an oversimplification, I doubt any answer would be useful or insightful.

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi basically, you understood my answer correctly. For the sampling scheme, i was suggesting a bayesian approach, which 1) incorporates a prior, so that you first guesses for $y_i$ are not random (but instead, guided by the prior) 2) samples at the *mean* instead of the *mode* of the distribution (which you would get by ML estimation).